# Troubleshooting a method to show/hide a div when a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, textarea

so I have the following HTML code for a checkbox and a hidden div containing a textarea that I need to appear when the checkbox is selected.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="q3resp4" value="1" onchange="valueChanged()"/> Other entity (specify):<br>
    <div style="display: none;" id="q3othertxt">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="q7resp"></textarea>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function valueChanged()
{
    if($('.q3resp4').is(":checked"))   
        $(".q3othertxt").show();
    else
        $(".q3othertxt").hide();
}
</script>
```

I'm not fluent with either language, so I may be making some rookie mistakes here, but every script/code snippet I tried has failed to give me results. So after doing ~90 minutes of research, I'm resorting to a straightforward question.

Thanks for any help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot in your jquery selectors is to match by class, not id or name.

```
function valueChanged()
{
    if($("input[name='q3resp4']").is(":checked"))   
        $("#q3othertxt").show();
    else
        $("#q3othertxt").hide();
}
```

Comment: So would I need start off the script with this instead?<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

Because right now that fix isn't doing anything for me. I think it may be the .show() and .hide() not existing in javascript.

Comment: Oh, yes, I assumed you were including jquery because you're using jquery selectors in your code.